# My azure subscription is gone in preview portal but still works on the management portal, how can I fix this?

Tags: azure

So I tried to login into the Preview portal only to find that my azure subscription is gone but still works on the management portal, how can I fix this? Is there someone I can contact about this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm you're looking at the correct directory? If you click on your name on the upper right corner, you get a list of the directories. Also, before your contact support (that's the way to fix it) completely logout and re-login.

Comment: I have both checked the directory and logged out and in, still it won't work. As this is clearly a Microsoft error, will I still have to pay for a support ticket? Thanks for your help

Comment: seems to be working now, maybe it was, as you said, the directory.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sometimes is just a cookie mix up. Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar problem. It seems Microsoft has changed its Login process to automate the selection of School/Work OR Personal account. If this automated process makes the wrong selection then you are logged into Azure with the wrong Active Directory so don't see any of your resources. In order to fix this issue you need to restart your PC and then login making the correct selection - School/Work OR Personal account.

I understand that in future when you create an account (say Joe.bloggs@hotmail.com) it must be either School/Work OR Personal. It cannot be both. Therefore there will be no a need to select School/Work OR Personal at login. This seems an excellent idea! It would be even better if Microsoft allowed you to set an existing account to either School/Work OR Personal in order to avoid such problems.